# node js having trouble with parsing of csv file useing fast-csv libary

Tags: node.js, csv

I'm using the [fast-csv](https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv) node library to parse a csv-file that looks like this

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream('./tmp_dir/'+files.fileUploaded.name);

var csvStream = csv()
    .on("data", function(data){
         console.log(data);
    })
    .on("end", function(){
         console.log("done");
    });

stream.pipe(csvStream);
```

I wonder if it is possible to do the following things

- To see how many rows in the csv file that could not be parsed?
- Record start and end time for parsing of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the link to the library github but you didn't read the doc!

It's all in here !

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream('./tmp_dir/'+files.fileUploaded.name);
var errorCount = 0;
var csvStream = csv.parse({strictColumnHandling: true, headers: true})
.on("data", function(data){
     console.log(data);
}).on("data-invalid", function(){
     console.log("error");
     errorCount += 1;
})    
.on("end", function(){
     console.log("done");
});

stream.pipe(csvStream);
```

For the timing you can just get the date when you read the first line (use a counter or a toggle isFirstLine that you set to false after read) and when you hit the finish event, and you'll have timing.

Comment: The event is called `data-invalid`.

Comment: And `headers` has to be set to `true` too I think.

Answer (score 0):

**1**

> To see how many rows in the csv file that could not be parsed?

In the [docs](https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv#parsing), it is mentioned that the event `data-invalid` is emitted when invalid row-data is encountered. *I'm not sure but* perhaps you can use that.

```
var csvStream = csv()
  .on("data-invalid", function(data){
     // handle the erroneous data
  })
  .on("data", function(data){
     console.log(data);
  })
  .on("end", function(){
     console.log("done");
  });
```

---

**2**

> Record start and end time for parsing of the file?

You could try this:

```
var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();

var csvStream = csv()
  .on("end", function(){
     console.log("done");

     var endTime = (new Date()).getTime();

     console.log("Time taken : ", (endTime - startTime));

  });
```

Comment: the data-invalid event will not be triggered as mentioned in the docs, because you need to specify a strict handling in the options, see my answer below.